# Calling WebService on OnCreate() causes performance Issue in android

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app i use TabGroupActivity for having multiple child under single tab. I used to call the web service in onCreate method of activity, whenever i navigate to child and click back button , the onCreate method will invoke again(second time), its seems performance is lower.

EX:` 
           @Override

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        getBundle = new Bundle();
        getBundle=getIntent().getExtras();           
        intentData = getBundle.getString("Search_Result");
        bikeItemList=new ArrayList<SearchResultsIdentifier>();
        System.out.println("sdf"+bikeItemList.size());
        DataService searchDS = new DataService();
        try {
            URL test=new URL(intentData);
            itemList=searchDS.getSearchList(test);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(tList.this,R.layout.search_bike,itemList,this));




    }`
```

How can i avoid this , as per android activity diagram when i navigate to child click bak onCreate won`t call, but here i use tab group activity. How to resolve twice web service call problem.

Answer (score 0):

Read that:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html
and that
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Threads
and **never ever start a long running task in UI interface**!

Comment: Actually i use thread to hit the service.... i just show  were i call the service.... i call the service using AsyncTask thats not a problem. But it called twice that is my problem

Comment: No, there is a problem. You call something like this `itemList=searchDS.getSearchList(test)`. In this place the programm is waiting for `getSearchList()` to return!

Comment: yeah, i do this operation in AsyncTask only , but my question is when i launch this activity it work fine, then i click the list navigate to next activity, when i click back from child again the onCreate method is invoked.

Comment: Both links provided are broken